# Removing a certain part of a string in python

Tags: python

"submitted 1 year ago by bagelpirate to /r/books"

Basically I'm learning about web scraping and I pulled this info from the html of a reddit page. I need to get "bagelpirate" out of this string.  Is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: Do you mean you want the string "bagelpirate", or do you mean you want to get rid of "bagelpirate" and leave everything else?

Comment: Yeah! Is there a way to go up to delete everything before "by" and after "to r/books"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the starting string:

```
s = "submitted 1 year ago by bagelpirate to /r/books"
```

You could do it like this (finding the position of the preceding and following substrings):

```
name = s[s.index(' by ')+4:s.index(' to /r/books')]
```

Or you could use a regular expression:

```
import re

name = re.search(' by (.+) to /r/books', s).group(1)
```

That means, 'find "by (something) to /r/books" in the string and give me the part indicated by parentheses'.

It kind of depends exactly what format the strings you get are actually going to be in.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [84]: s = "submitted 1 year ago by bagelpirate to /r/books"

In [85]: s.replace("bagelpirate", '')
Out[85]: 'submitted 1 year ago by  to /r/books'
```